# Can't update build.gradle to use support library 23.0.1

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

So I've updated my build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

But when I try to sync the project this pops up

```
Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

(and the same for the other two repositories)

Then I try to click "Install Repository and sync project" and this error occurs:

```
Ignoring unknown package filter 'extra-android-m2repository'Warning: 
The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.
```

And install fails.

I have installed build tools 23.0.1 and everything for android M in SDK manager.
Tried rolling back to 23.0.0 but it's the same.

What's wrong? Where did this package filter came from? I dont think I changed anything except for build.gradle before this error occured

EDIT: I tried to delete build tools and install them again and while installing SDK manager log popped up with this:

```
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 23.0.1
Installing Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 23.0.1
*** -> Stopping ADB server failed (code -1)
Installed Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 23.0.1
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.1
Installing Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.1
Installed Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.1
Stopping ADB server succeeded.
Starting ADB server succeeded.
Done. 2 packages installed.
Done loading packages.
```

Comment: Did you also update the Android SDK Tools, Android Support Repository and Android Support Library?

Comment: @buzeeg I have. The project now works on my other machine (before, there was error on both of my computers). Don't know how it was fixed though :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First make sure that you set

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

and

```
targetSdkVersion 23
```

Then press Sync Project with Gradle Files and install everything that is missing.

Next, add your

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

and make sure that you are **NOT** trying to add this

```
compile 'com.android.support:design-v7:23.0.1'
```

it should work now.

Answer (score 2):

In my case Reinstalling Android Studio fixed the bug. I guess something wrong was with network.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling Android Studio fixed the problem.

My guess is that Android Studio did not have internet access

Comment: In this particular case, reinstalling the AS is redundant. Please check my answer to fix issue without need to reinstall AS

Answer (score 0):

Did you try updating the compileSdkVersion in your build.gradle to 23 as well?

It appears like several people are having related issues. If updating the compile sdk does not work either, maybe you can try any of the solutions in this thread: [Error retrieving parent for Item - AppCompat-v7 23](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183122)

Comment: I have. Actually i noticed that none of the android studio projects work on this PC (on my second PC it works). So I think project configuration has nothing to do wth it. I'll try reinstalling android studio